# drop down list not loading option on editform using PHP array

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I've got a list of records with edit links on them. When i click on the link it takes me to an edit page with the results from the database.

I can retrieve the data successfully for all the text boxes.

I'm trying to implement this via an array which fails to work.

Here is my implementation in code fragments:

```
        # $data is from $data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)


                        $product=$data['product'];
                        echo $product.'<br />';

        #initializing array to empty
           $product_list=array("Remote"=>" ","TV"=>" ","Box"=>" ");

        if (array_key_exists($product,$product_list)){


            $product_list["'$product'"] =  'selected="selected" ';


            }

                            print_r($product_list);


        #combo box 

              <select name="products">
                        <option value="select">Select</option>
                        <option value="Remote"<?php echo @$product_list["'$product'"] ?>>Remote</option>
                        <option value="TV" <?php echo @$product_list["'$product'"] ?>> TV</option>
                        <option value="Box" <?php echo @$product_list["'$product'"] ?>> Box</option>
                    </select>
```

In the page that displays all the records if i hit edit on a record that has product 'Remote' i get the following output(as per echo statements above):

```
Remote
Array ( [Remote] => [TV] => [Box] => ['Remote'] => selected="selected" )
```

The HTML form displays:

```
 <select name="products">                   
    <option value="select">Select</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Remote">Remote</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="TV"> TV</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Box"> Box</option>
</select>
```

In the edit page if i select a record that has product 'TV' i get the following output:

```
 TV
 Array ( [Remote] => [TV] => [Box] => ['TV'] => selected="selected" )
```

HTML output is same as above. **And it always sets the option to the last product which is 'Box'.**

Can somebody please advise on how i can fix this? thanks!

Comment: You explicitly specifying that all the options in the `<select>` tag are to be selected, that is why your getting the complete list of `options` in the edit page. Also if it is a drop-down list, specify `size=1` attribute in select tag.

Comment: Thanks, i meant to say drop down box : ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$product_list["'$product'"] =  'selected="selected" ';
```

should be

```
$product_list[$product] =  'selected="selected" ';
```

And in other places that have `$product_list["'$product'"]` you should also remove quotes.

Edit:

Here

```
<select name="products">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="Remote"<?php echo @$product_list["'$product'"] ?>>Remote</option>
    <option value="TV" <?php echo @$product_list["'$product'"] ?>> TV</option>
    <option value="Box" <?php echo @$product_list["'$product'"] ?>> Box</option>
</select>
```

you are not using any loop and trying to get the value of `$product_list[$product]` in every item - $product will always be the same in every line and equal to the last one fetched from mysql.

You have either to use correct index in each line (ie. `<?php echo $product_list['TV']; ?>`) or proper way - use the loop:

```
<select name="products">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <?php foreach($product_list as $product_name => $selected): ?>
    <option value="<?= $product_name ?>" <?= $selected ?>><?= $product_name ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```